# Users last login date - Drupal

Tags: drupal

In drupal how to  display the user's last login date and Time.I tried out the code 
user->login
It displays the current login time, But I want users previous login time and date.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [User Stats module](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats), it might be something that could work for you.  From the module's project page:

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address tracking and Views
>   integration.  Statistics are:
>
> - Days registered
> - Join date
> - Days since last login
> - Days since last post
> - Post count
> - Login count
> - User online/offline
> - IP address

Answer (score 1):

These data are saved with module [Login History](http://drupal.org/project/login_history)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't offer this natively. If you need to use it, you would probably want to add it to for example serialized $user->data array when user logs in (Using hook_user() for $op = "login") and save updated user object afterwards, and then you will be able to fetch it on the next login.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used: keep track of the last two log-in timestamps (the current and the previous one).

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_user()
 */
function your_module_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch($op) {

    // Successful login
    case 'load':
      // If it's less than two it means we don't have a previous login timtestamp yet.
      $account->custom_last_login = sizeof($account->custom_login_history) < 2 
        ? NULL 
        : array_pop($account->custom_login_history); 
      break;

    case 'login':
      // If it's the first time, we don't have a history
      $login_history = is_array($account->custom_login_history) 
        ? $account->custom_login_history 
        : array();

      // Get rid of the old value.
      if (sizeof($login_history) == 2) {
        array_pop($login_history);
      }

      // Add to the history the current login timestamp.
      array_unshift($login_history, $account->login);

      user_save($account, array('custom_login_history' => $login_history));
      break;
  }
}
```

Then in your template you just use `$user->custom_last_login`. If it's empty it means we don't have the previous timestamp yet, will be available after the next login.